# How do I install EMT conduit for an outdoor 6/4 power run?

Tags: electrical, conduit

I need to run NEMA 14-50 50A outlet from the breaker show to the garage (approximately 30') . From the red line, I plan to run 1" EMT conduit as show in the picture, four #6 wiring inside, 50A breaker and such.

- I will pull permit from the city (Dublin, CA )
- Breaker (Square D) is 200A with only AC connected.
- A DIY doable ? what tool do I need to bend and assemble the  conduit ?

  Quote is over 1k ..

[image]

Comment: If you want to bend it, you'll need a [1" conduit bender](http://www.idealind.com/products/wire_installation/conduit_benders/ductile_iron_benders.jsp). If you don't want to bend it, you can buy 90° sweeps instead. If you want to stay tight to the building, you could use [conduit bodies](http://i00.i.aliimg.com/img/pb/914/810/432/432810914_516.jpg).

Comment: To emphasize @Tester101's point, you are almost certainly going to want to use conduit bodies or another type of fitting called a pull elbow on any outside corners and probably also on the inside corners. The bend radius of 1" EMT is over 5 inches, so if you bend into and around corners, you will have some uglies, especially on the around-corners part. Of course, everyone has a different definition of ugly.

Comment: @mjohns I believe 1" EMT benders have an 8" take up, not 5".

Comment: @Tester101 you are correct. I have 1/2" on the brain.

Comment: $1000 is an absolute BARGAIN for this job. ...IMO 1" EMT in a rather complex run like this is not at all beginner DIY work, especially if you are coming from an outdoor panel and have to ask "How do I do this".

Comment: I would consider running it on the bottom close to ground or even buried a little.  It's going look hideous up top.

Answer (score 2):

It is definitely doable.  Like @Tester101 indicates, you need a conduit bender.  They are available at the big-box stores.  Will be a little more expensive than you might like.  So will wire.  A pipe cutter, like the plumbers use would be advantageous to make your cuts square.  And, of course, you need a drill suitable to make a hole through your house. Other than that, you need a screwdriver, tape measure and pencil.

Your biggest challenge will be maintaining your patience.  Bending conduit is not intuitive.  You should do a little study before you start, and recognize that you're going to make a couple of miss-bends.

Comment: You DO NOT use _"a pipe cutter like the plumbers use"_ for electrical EMT conduit. It will leave far too deep of a burr that will take a ton of grinding to get rid of. A simple hack saw is all that is required. If you can't make a square cut on 1/2" thru 1" EMT you shouldn't be cutting it in the first place.
They did make similar cutters for EMT but finding one will be kind of hard since no one bought them. I haven't seen one for sale in a while.

Comment: @SpeedyPetey Not the case.  I've done dozens of cuts.  You don't have to cut all the way through, and reaming the aluminum is no problem.

Comment: @SpeedyPetey Why don't you try it?  Just score the EMT deep enough to snap the tube.

Comment: I have tried it. I have the Greenlee cutter and it sucks. The method it uses, and as you suggest, it terrible. Also, you did not say that at first. You simply said to use a plumbing tubing cutter. Lastly, EMT is steel, not aluminum. It reams, but the deep burr a tubing cutter leaves is horrible and dangerous to wire being pulled.

Comment: .@SpeedyPetey is right, most EMT is steel.  I have not had the same experience he has had with the problems associated with excess burring.

Answer (score 0):

I would use an condulet called an LB on the outside corrners to tuck in tight , also if using EMT outside you need compression type fittings not set screw type for both your couplings and box ends
I use a standard cutoff blade and a EMT reamer to deburr the inside of the pipe so the burs dont cut the insulation (kline makes one looks like a screwdriver with 3 hooks on the side mine does 1/2"-3/4" & 1")

Comment: +0.  Fair answer, but please use periods to split your answer into discrete sentences.  Also please fix your spelling and punctuation.